# Can I still develop for the current iOS 4 with iOS 5 beta installed?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

I would like to install the iOS Beta 3 on my iPhone 4 but I also have a couple of updates I'm working on that I want to submit in the coming weeks. So I was wondering can I still submit these app updates if I've tested them using iOS 5 Beta 3 on my device?

Comment: Perhaps you should read the documentation from Apple with regards submitting apps using the Betas.  And while you're there, you could read the NDA that you've signed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all you should never install a beta on a device that isn't dedicated to testing as it will be insanely buggy.

Other than that you should be fine providing you...

1) Install the iOS 5 SDK in a separate directory because the beta SDK can't submit apps to the App Store.

2) Don't use any iOS 5 specific APIs in your app because this will cause issues on any other OS version.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to download the beta of Xcode that works with iOS 5 in order to test them on your device, and this version of Xcode is not enabled for submitting apps to the App Store.